# ¿como puedo consultar en Mysql solo los nombres iguales de una tabla producto?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi Tabla producto es esto:

Tabla producto

```
id  Nombre  precio  stock 
1   Zapato  $45.00  40  
2   Zapato  $23.00  30  
3   Zapato  $23.00  30  
4   jeans   $28.00  10  
5   lentes  $89.00  20
```

Este es un pequeño tabla que no logro hacer una consulta,donde la consulta solo imprima todo la fila "zapato" solo esos 3, o que solo imprima la fila "jean" quien me podría explicar gracias.

Algo asi:

```
   "Zapato"
    id  Nombre  precio  stock 
    1   Zapato  $45.00  40  
    2   Zapato  $23.00  30  
    3   Zapato  $23.00  30

    "jean"
    id  Nombre  precio  stock   
    4   jeans   $28.00  10
```

Comment: No se si entendí bien
`SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Nombre  = 'Zapato';` 
Esto solo mostrara los que son de nombre zapato

Comment: Gracias Hecto Lara me funciono a la perfección.

Comment: Siempre a la orden hermano.
Te recomiendo la documentación para que te guíes mejor  [PHP Select Data From MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Gracias por la Guía @HectorLara esta muy bueno.

Answer (score 3):

Si requieres obtener en tu consulta Zapatos o Jean debes hacer uso del WHERE de la siguiente manera:

Para Zapato

```
SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Nombre = 'Zapato';
```

Para Jean

```
SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Nombre = 'Jean';
```

Comment: Quedo elegante gracias por el aporte Anyel, eso era la que estaba buscando.

Comment: de Nada cualquier problema no dudes en contactarme, Salduos !!